# Changing a 24 clock to a 12 using BlueJ

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, clock, bluej

```
private void updateDisplay()
{   
    if(hours.getValue() == 0)
    {
        hours.setValue(12);
        displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
        minutes.getDisplayValue() + " am"; 
    }
    else if(hours.getValue() < 12)
    {
        displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
        minutes.getDisplayValue() + " am";
    }
    else if(hours.getValue() == 12)
    {
        displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
        minutes.getDisplayValue() + " pm";
    }
    else if(hours.getValue() < 24)
    { 
        displayString = Integer.toString(hours.getValue() - 12) + ":" +  
        minutes.getDisplayValue() + " pm"; 
    }
}
```

I'm only suppose to use this method to change the display of the clock.. Ive been working on it for hours but i am getting stuck because for some reason in this method it keeps jumping starting to the else statement even though the values being entered meet the if requirements. Below i will display relevant parts of other class i am using..EDITED Now just wont stay in AM when rolls midnight

```
public int getValue()
{
    return value;
}

// Return the display value (that is, the current value as a two-digit
// String. If the value is less than ten, it will be padded with a leading
// zero).
public String getDisplayValue()
{
    if(value < 10) {
        return "0" + value;
    }
    else {
        return "" + value;
    }
}

// Set the value of the display to the new specified value. If the new
// value is less than zero or over the limit, do nothing.
public void setValue(int replacementValue)
{
    if((replacementValue >= 0) && (replacementValue < limit)) {
        value = replacementValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I'm only suppose to use this method"* Is this [tag:homework]?  If so, it is advantageous to tag it as such.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed an `else`:

```
private void updateDisplay()
{
  if(hours.getValue() < 12)
     displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" +
            minutes.getDisplayValue() + " am";

 [this one] >>>> else if(hours.getValue() >= 12 && hours.getValue() < 25)
     displayString = Integer.toString(hours.getValue() - 12) + ":" + 
            minutes.getDisplayValue() + " pm";

  else {
    hours.setValue(12);
    displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
                    minutes.getDisplayValue() + " am";
  }
}
```

**Added:**

You can also use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format your time. Here's how:

```
SimpleDateFormat from = new SimpleDateFormat("H");
SimpleDateFormat to = new SimpleDateFormat("h a");

return to.format(from.parse(hours.getValue));
```

**Added2:**

If you **need** to calculate it manually, easiest way would be this:

```
if (hours.getValue() == 0) {
    return "12 am";
} else if (hours.getValue() < 12) {
    return hours.getValue() + " am";
} else if (hours.getValue() == 12) {
    return "12 pm";
} else if (hours.getValue() < 24) {
    return (hours.getValue()-12) + " pm";
} else {
    throw new ParseException("Invalid hours value: "+hours.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Do you know how i could add a rollover from 12 to 1 am and pm?

Comment: @user1388557 Added information on how to use SimpleDateFormat. I think you should consider using it.

Comment: Thank you but I gotta stick to if or switch statments..(Haven't technically learned that yet) I would write a switch which I know would work but that would be writing 24 different cases.

Comment: Dude thank you, I swear ive been trying new things for past 5 hours straight

Comment: Still thought once I tick over from 1159 pm to 1200 am..once it hits 1201 it goes pm